# Object Help Parse iOS SDK? Relational data perhaps?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I've been working with the Parse SDK for iOS and have hit a stump in logic when trying to make something happen.

I currently have two Classes, a User one, and For Sale one. I want to make it so users can ultimately hit a UIButton on a Detail View Controller of a For Sale object and have that  For Sale object be added to a ' Watching list' for the user which will be a separate UIViewController with a UITableView with these Watching objects.

Where do I start? Do I use relational data? I'm confused!